# C++ - Weird function return value

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2015

I was making a simple min() function when I suddenly asked myself a question which got a bit more complex than I though

I created a valid function, and got the idea to omit a condition between the two numbers. Here is my function:

```
int min(int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) {
        return y;
    }
    else if (x < y) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

So it works perfectly for different numbers, if I put 2 and 3 inside, it'll return 2.
But what happen when I put two time the same number? e.g. : 2 and 2

Neither 2 > 2 and 2 < 2 are valid, so it's just returning... nothing?

That what I though, I compiled the program (VS2015), got a warning about not testing every cases (normal), and when it runs... it outputs 2. Why?

After talking with people on it (and checking the ASM code for this function), someone checked with Valgrind what was happening, and as he told me, it appears that it could be a memory leak. I don't exactly know how it works, so why returning no value make it returning 2? Which 2 is returned?

I also tested if one of these conditions were true for some reason with a simple std::cout, but none of theme are true, so that's not something about "simplifying" with `if (x > y) {...} else {...}`

So what is really happening here?

[EDIT] I don't wanna know how to "fix" it, because it's pretty obvious to me. The question is, why am I getting 2? I know that there should be an else statement, but I was curious about what will happen without it

Comment: If you compiled this with warnings enabled, you'd see something like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function`. If you're not seeing warnings like that, you should change your compiler settings to allow you to see them, because it's very useful. The key here is that you don't have a final else clause.

Comment: I really fail to see why people want to gamble on undefined behaviour when they can just fix the code...

Comment: @Baum mit Augen The proposed duplicate does not answer the question why the function in question is returning `2`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Do you think so? The accepted answer correctly explains how the missing return value is produced from `eax` in a not so different example and that it depends on the calling convention.

Comment: *The question is, why am I getting 2?* -- Generate the assembly code and take a look at it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: sorry, you're right. It's on the very last line and I missed it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so why

`int min(int x, int y) {
 if (x > y) {
  return y;
 }
 else if (x < y) {
  return x;
 }

 int z = 3;
}

int main() {
 std::cout << min(2, 2) << std::endl;

 return{ 0 };
}
`
isn't returning 3?

Comment: @LucasBenard  Please [see this](http://rextester.com/AUZBQ80385).  With optimizations turned on Visual Studio 2015 returns garbage.  So you're going to spend time finding out why garbage is returned?

Comment: @LucasBenard The assignment gets probably optimized away by dead code optimization. If you care about the precise inner working of this flavor of UB in this special case, read up on the calling convention in use and check the generated assembly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so the only reason why I'm getting 2, is that VS15 just take the last number? With another compiler, it should give me what the link you gave me returned?

Comment: @LucasBenard The compiler used at the link **is** Visual Studio 2015, but with optimizations tuned on (not "debug" mode).  The point being is that it gets pointless in spending time on something you can't predict.  Maybe in the next version of Visual Studio, you get -32434, 0, 13, 8927, 2, you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how and why exactly it behaves, you need to study the *calling convention* used here.

I believe the typical x86 C/C++ calling convention is to `push` (as in, the ASM command) the arguments onto the stack, `call` the function, and then `pop` the result. In case you skip both `if` branches and don't call `return`, there is no `push` instruction generated. But the caller will still `pop`. What will it pop? Whatever ends up on the stack in that spot, which could be anything - there's no way of knowing. And I think it will corrupt the stack in doing so, or more precisely - put it in the state that the other stack users don't expect. The program may stop working properly altogether, the way I see it, since your stack is mixed up now. Bottom line: don't let non-`void` function exit without a `return` statement, ever.

Update: I looked at the actual assembly using Godbolt (e. g. https://godbolt.org/z/8emYlB) and I can now see I was wrong about the calling convention typically used; looks like the stack isn't used for return values, `eax` register is. So at least a missing `return` will not cause heap corruption, but you will still get an undefined return value - whatever happened to be in the accumulator register at that moment.

Answer (score 3):

Flowing off the end of a function results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function. The behavior of your program is undefined.

In practice this means the caller is going to try to read the returned `int` according to whatever calling convention is being used, and fail to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything when `x` and `y` are equal. As a consequence, the program has undefined behavior when `x` is equal to `y`.

Use:

```
int min(int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) {
        return y;
    }
    else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a point worth making, and the right way to implement this.

Comment: @JuanTomas: it's tagged C++. The right way is `std::min`. Or at least the one-liner: `return x < y ? x : y;`

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to write your own `min()`.  But yeah, the ternary operator is arguably the better way.  What I zeroed in on was the mistaken `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an `else` statement because the 2=2 neither fulfills the `if(x > y)` condition, nor it fulfills the `else if(x < y)` condition. So it can't return anything. Just add an `else` and return the same x value.

```
int min(int x, int y) 
{
    if (x > y)
    {
        return y;
    }
    else 
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```